# SQL Query that selects only one duplicate record, based on the highest date value in that record

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I have a table below that shows employee details, along with a 'dateValue', which is a number based off when the employee clocked into work. As you can see, 'Dave' has clocked in twice today, but I only want to see Dave's most recent clock in (The larger the number, the more recent the clock in)

ID is a column in both the 'employee' and 'clock' database that links the two database's together, this is unique to each employee.

SQL for table below

```
SELECT e.name, e.country, e.role, e.age, c.dateValue FROM employee e left join clock c on e.ID = c.ID

   | e.name  | e.country|   e.role   |e.age| c.dateValue | c.ID |
    
   | Dave    | England  | Programmer | 45  |     013     |  1   |
   | Gary    | Scotland | Engineer   | 44  |     033     |  2   |
   | Brian   | USA      | Engineer   | 67  |     042     |  4   |
   | Dave    | England  | Programmer | 45  |     019     |  1   |
   | Lucy    | England  | Sales      | 35  |     033     |  5   |
```

Desired result:

```
   | e.name  | e.country|   e.role   |e.age| c.dateValue | c.ID |
    
   | Gary    | Scotland | Engineer   | 44  |     033     |  2   |
   | Brian   | USA      | Engineer   | 67  |     042     |  4   |
   | Dave    | England  | Programmer | 45  |     019     |  1   |
   | Lucy    | England  | Sales      | 35  |     033     |  5   |
```

In my desired result, Dave's first clock in is not displayed, as I want to display only one of each employee, whether they've clocked in once, or 100 times today, I only want to show their most recent clock in, where the c.dateValue is the highest, and grouping by e.name

SQL I have tried:

```
SELECT e.name, e.country, e.role, e.age, c.dateValue FROM employee e left join clock c on e.ID = c.ID group by e.name where MAX(c.dateValue) AS date 


SELECT e.name, e.country, e.role, e.age, MAX(c.dateValue) AS date FROM employee e left join clock c on e.ID = c.ID group by e.name
```

For both attempts of my SQL above, I get the error: " 'employee.country' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause "

Answer (score 0):

You need filtering, not aggregation. I would recommend `row_number()` (available in MySQL 8.0 only):

```
select name, country, role, age, datevalue
from (
    select e.*, c.datevalue, row_number() over(partition by c.datevalue order by e.id desc) rn
    from employee e 
    inner join clock c on e.id = c.id
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: I have implemented the code you supplied, and I am now getting the error 'The column 'datevalue' was specified multiple times for 't'.'